# Extract a float from a string Python

Tags: python, int, extract

I have a string which looks like this :

```
'< 5s' or '< 0.5s'
```

And i'm trying to extract the 'duration' from the string. I already have this :

```
a = '< 5s'
b = int(list(filter(str.isdigit, a))[0])
print(b)
```

but if i use `'< 0.5s'` it returns me `0`. How can i include the `,` with the number ?

Comment: looks like a job for regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple regex:

```
import re

s = '< 0.5s'
dur = re.search(r'-?\d+(\.\d+)?', s).group()
print(dur)   # 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
b = re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", a)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `b = float(a[2:-1])` should do the trick, if you are certain that the string is always formatted exactly as shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`, maybe something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
inp="< 0.5s 5s -12z34 -6.7s"
for i in re.findall("-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+", inp):
    print(i)
```